# Merge Tags [web-mediarecorder] and [mediarecorder-api]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The two tags [web-mediarecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-mediarecorder) and [mediarecorder-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediarecorder-api) have around 18 questions each, almost<sup>1</sup> all referring to the JavaScript [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) API. It's unclear which to use, so using both seems to be the only option right now. Can we merge these tags?

[web-mediarecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-mediarecorder) is probably the least-ambiguous name for the reason below.

To complicate things, there's also the [mediarecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediarecorder) tag with 617 questions, of which 586+ are about the same-named android API, and only 14 are tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). There's also an [android-mediarecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mediarecorder) tag for symmetry.

<sup>1</sup> [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediarecorder-api+android) android questions are marked [mediarecorder-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediarecorder-api) that would need to be fixed.